# Static function for work Thread

Tags: c#, static

hi i change one of my programs that i added a Thread for its functions but i have an error

it is the first time i worked on Threads. I'm getting an error in `*.Checked == true`

```
static bool Check_DIR_Attributes(DirectoryInfo DirInfo)
    {
        //check Attributes
        FileAttributes Fattributes = new FileAttributes();
        Fattributes = DirInfo.Attributes;

        SearchSetAttrib = new List<FileAttributes>();

        if (chkattributes.Checked == true)
        {
            SearchSetAttrib.Clear();
            if (chkreadonly.Checked == true)
                SearchSetAttrib.Add(FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
            if (chksystem.Checked == true)
                SearchSetAttrib.Add(FileAttributes.System);
            if (chkhidden.Checked == true)
                SearchSetAttrib.Add(FileAttributes.Hidden);
            if (chkNormal.Checked == true)
                SearchSetAttrib.Add(FileAttributes.Normal);
            if (chkArchiv.Checked == true)
                SearchSetAttrib.Add(FileAttributes.Archive);

            foreach (FileAttributes FileAtt in SearchSetAttrib)
            {
                if ((Fattributes & (FileAtt)) != 0)
                    ReAttrib = true;
                else
                    return ReAttrib = false;
            }
        }
        else
            ReAttrib = true;

        return ReAttrib;
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: An Object Reference is Required for the non-static field , Or property Search_File.Form1.chkAttributes

Comment: @locerst look at the answer below.

Comment: Could you show us how you're managing your thread(s)?

Answer (score 2):

The fields `chkreadonly`, `chksystem` etc. are not static (and they can't easily be), so accessing them from a **static** method will not work.

My recommendation is to

- either make the function non-static
- or (if that is not possible for some reason) use a non-static wrapper to provide the static method with a reference to the instance

Comment: did you just assume that those variables were instance variables because of their name (checkboxes)? :)

Comment: @locerst why do you think that method has to be static in order to be used for a thread?

Comment: @aiapatag The title was the giveaway!

Comment: @locerst if you start the Thread **inside** the class, you don't need to change anything. If you start the Thread **outside** the class, replace the class name with the instance name in `new Thread(xxx.Check_DIR_Attributes)`